# Cannot build fracplanet

Tags: graphics, generator, terrain, fractals

I'm interested in fractals lately, so I've done some research. While searching I've found out this application: [fracplanet](http://www.bottlenose.demon.co.uk/share/fracplanet/)
I've tried to build it but I did not succeed. Can you please help me? I've tried it on Ubuntu. It would be great if you could help me. Thanks

Comment: Could you please post the build errors or some more information about the problems

Comment: Thanks.  You've just made me realize the "Where to get it" info on fracplanet is hopelessly out of date (compared with sister project evolvotron http://www.bottlenose.demon.co.uk/share/evolvotron/download.htm ).  Will update it at some point!

Answer (score 1):

fracplanet is actually available as a ["universe" package for the last few Ubuntu releases](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/graphics/fracplanet).

If you just want to *use* fracplanet, install the package via Ubuntu's package manager and away you go.

If you really need to *build* it yourself to mod the code etc, inspecting the Ubuntu source package should give some insight into build dependencies, Ubuntu specific patches etc.  When I build fracplanet on Debian (squeeze), the build dependencies are (verified in pbuilder):

```
qt4-qmake libqt4-dev libqt4-opengl-dev libboost-dev libboost-program-options-dev xsltproc
```

So just installing those (assuming the same exist on Ubuntu) might well fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The FracPlanet is built with Qt. That might be troublesome for you - you didn't post the exact errors yet.

There is an alternative project - [Real-Time procedural universe](http://sponeil.net/). It's worth to take a look there. All the sources are included and it does not depend on any monstrous frameworks like Qt.

Comment: I have plenty of boost related errors. I've loaded the boost library and Qt and still not working. I must have done something wrong.

Comment: Hmm...I've dowloaded this source code. I'm trying to figure out how it works, but I still don't manage to make it work. what should I use to compile it?

Comment: Talking about Ubuntu, things must be simple there. We need at least _some_ error messages, because what you call "boost-related" might be just some missing files or some wrong paths in makefile. Do you have all the build-essentials, gcc, autotools and other stuff installed ?